# Trigger function to append column to insert, syntax error at or near "NEW"

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_z
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON test_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_z();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_z()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
zs record;
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM geography_columns where f_geography_column not like '%_z' AND f_table_name like TG_TABLE_NAME into zs;
  EXECUTE 'NEW.'
            || quote_ident(zs.f_geography_column)
            || '_z:= ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(NEW.'
            || quote_ident(zs.f_geography_column)
            || '::geometry), ST_Y(NEW.'
            || quote_ident(zs.f_geography_column)
            || '::geometry), 0), 4326)';                          
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION set_z()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Error Logs:

```
2017-06-20 09:27:43 MDT ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NEW" at character 1
2017-06-20 09:27:43 MDT QUERY:  NEW.location_z := ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(NEW.location::geometry), ST_Y(NEW.location::geometry), 0), 4326)
2017-06-20 09:27:43 MDT CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function set_z() line 7 at EXECUTE
```

I've created a new column in an existing table that I'm trying to keep updated using a trigger/trigger function. Everything seems to be working fine until the trigger function executes. The location_z column exists in the table with PointZ type, but is not part of the insert which triggers this trigger function.

Let me know if you need any more info to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only execute SQL commands with `EXECUTE`, not PL/pgSQL statements like an assignment.

I can't think of a simple way to assign values to a variable column in `NEW`; maybe you could query the system catalogs, compose a tuple as string and use something like:

```
new_tuple = $$(1, 'something', ...)::test_table$$;
EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || new_tuple INTO NEW;
```

Comment: I ended up just swapping the trigger to AFTER, and then doing a SELECT for null values in the missing field. It works but I don't really like it. I'll take a stab at this and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for the explanation on what was causing the error, I was truly lost.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I'm too inexperienced to get it to work. Also, I ended up having to make a trigger function for each table for other reasons, so now I don't need the EXECUTE and should be able to use a BEFORE trigger and NEW.